# Trying to create full-height window, menus top and bottom, with scrolling centre content

Tags: css, fullscreen

I'm trying to configure a site to have an always-full-page format, top and bottom menu bars that are always top and bottom, and the central content of the page sitting between them, with scrollbars. The central content need be the only part of the page that scrolls.

I'm nearly there, but I can't get the central content to sit within them, it starts below the top menu, always runs behind the bottom menu.

I've stripped back and centralised the code from the site, if you resize the screen you'll see the content runs behind the bottom menu.

Any pointers? Help much appreciated

(Forgive the  comments, when I try and debug I always get lost, so putting these there as I code them makes it easier!!)

Here'sa link to the faulty page:
[www.marinersipswich.co.uk/new2/test.htm](http://www.marinersipswich.co.uk/new2/test.htm)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="topmenu">
Top Menu Here
</div><!-- end topmenu -->


<div id="content">

Blah Blah Other content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>


</div><!--End content-->

<div id="bottommenu">
Bottom Menu Here
</div><!-- end bottommenu -->



</div><!-- end container -->

<style type="text/css">

html {
height:100%;
margin:0;
}


body {
height:100%;
margin:0;
background-color: #ffffff;
font: 12px Arial;
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
overflow:hidden;
}


#container {
height:99%;
max-height:100%;
min-height:100%;
width:90%;
max-width:1500px;
min-height:400px;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color:#e9e9e9;
}


#content{
margin:20px;
position:relative;
height:100%;
max-height:100%;
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:auto;
}


#topmenu{
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
text-align:center;
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;
margin: 40px 0 0;
width: 100%;
position:relative;
background-color:#00ff00;
}


#bottommenu{
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
text-align:center;
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;
margin: -80px 0 0;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
bottom: 20px;
left: 0;
background-color:#00ff00;
}


</style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so you want fixed header and fixed bottom?

Comment: let me know if is this what you want : http://jsfiddle.net/5mmR8/2/

Comment: Thanks dippas, very nearly but rather than specifying a height I would like the content to stop short of the bottom menu, no matter what size the window is. I tried margin-bottom:100px;  but it hasn't made a difference. so content height = 100& minus the bottom menu height. Margin-bottom makes sense, but isn't changing anything!

Comment: But you want to have scrollbar in your ´.content' ?

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/NZP9v/16/show/ - works with any height.

Comment: Ok I misunderstood the question, i thought he wants to scroll inside the #content...besides having the browser scrollbar.

Comment: This is one with scroll on the content and max-width: http://fiddle.jshell.net/nZK6Q/4/show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two fixed positioned containers top and bottom with z-index to avoid text being visible when scrolled. Top and bottom margin for the content container. That's it

**Scroll on the body**
http://fiddle.jshell.net/NZP9v/16/show/
http://fiddle.jshell.net/NZP9v/16
And a variation with extra container inside the fixed positioned top and bottom container with max-width. http://fiddle.jshell.net/hAvA8/3/show

**Scroll on the content container**
Here a variation with scroll on the content: http://fiddle.jshell.net/u6VzU/4/show
And a variation with extra container inside the fixed positioned top and bottom container with max-width with the scroll on content: http://fiddle.jshell.net/nZK6Q/5/show/

**scroll on the content container with a max-height**
http://fiddle.jshell.net/ZmPv5/1/show
**The CSS for full-height window, menus top and bottom, with scrolling centred content**
http://fiddle.jshell.net/zu2zq/2/show

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}
.max-width {
    background-color: #00FF00;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1500px;
    padding: 10px;
}
#container {
    background-color: #E9E9E9;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 40px auto;
    max-width: 1500px;
    position: relative;
}
#content {
    border-bottom: 80px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 100%;
    margin: 40px 0 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
#topmenu {
    height: 40px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
#bottommenu {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 40px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

The fixed container needs an extra div to make the centered nax-width play ok.

```
<div id="topmenu">
  <div class="max-width">Top Menu Here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, not exactly as I  had it pictured, but certainly a workable answer!
Only being picky I had the menu bars locked within the boundaries of the main container, so the page could be narrower than full width of the screen etc, or have borders all around the edges. With position:fixed they aren't relative to the size of the container any more.
Also I imagined the content div itself to have the scrollbars, like an iframe would if I'd linked the content in there.
I guess fixed position is the key to this answer though

Comment: In most cases we put the scroll on the body as it is not a small box with overflow.

Comment: I guess I'd make life much easier for myself if I did it your way and made the whole site full screen! Silly when I get an image of what I want before I begin, and take so many hours struggling to get unnecessary things right!

Comment: This is from all the variations what you wanted: scroll on the container and max-width: http://fiddle.jshell.net/nZK6Q/4/show/

Comment: Thanks Johan, I really appreciate the help. For some reason the last example has the content running behind the lower menu again doesn't it? I think I'll go with the full screen example, perhaps I can get the fixed position menus to mimic the 90% width and centered style of the container so they look like they are contained!

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/nZK6Q/4/show/ works in Firefox but not Chrome there the scroll is hidden at the bottom

Comment: Ah, I see! Annoying how different browsers do that!
Thanks so much! I guess as long as I leave a bit of space under any content I use, then it will never be an issue.

Thanks so much Johan!

Comment: Fixed it! http://fiddle.jshell.net/zu2zq/2/ for all browsers. Forgot te box-sizing for Chrome... http://fiddle.jshell.net/zu2zq/2/show

Comment: Just add the 2 lines of code for the box-sizing. And it will be fine.

Comment: Awesome! Just awesome. good work! I'll show you the finished item when it's done! Thanks

Comment: I've implemented your code to the page I'm about to create (getting the structure right before any content is added of course http://www.marinersipswich.co.uk/new2/

No idea why the top and bottom menus are sitting indented from the left though http://www.marinersipswich.co.uk/new2/scripts/style.css

Comment: .max-width  {max-width: 1500px;} you have copied from my example 1000px - Though I like it more when the scroll is on the body though. Personal preference I guess. http://fiddle.jshell.net/hAvA8/3/show/

Comment: max-width needs to be same value.

Comment: Changed the width of the top and bottom menus to 90% to match the container. Even though they started from the left edge of the container, they still copied the 100% page width, therefore always shot off the page!